# Android ksoap2, data not being post

Tags: ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 for communicating with a remote web service. For some reason, the properties I add to soapObject are not being sent. Where have I gotten wrong? I have tried everything, I get a response when I perform direct posting of the request xml but that is not what I want. I also get a response from the server but none of the values I post are being passed. I have read every blog out there, the official documentation and even related SO questions, What have I missed?

Here is a snippet of a method being called from the doInBackground() of Async Task.

```
public SoapObject getSoapObject() {
        // Create request
        SoapObject requesty = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        // Add the property to request object
        requesty.addProperty(getPropertyInfo("PARAMETER_1", "VALUE_1"));

        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requesty);

        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapObject soapObject = null;
        try {
            // Send to web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);       
            soapObject =  (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return soapObject;
    }

    private PropertyInfo getPropertyInfo(String name, String value) {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.setName(name);
        propInfo.setValue(value);
        propInfo.setType(string.class);
        return propInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ksoap2, I posted directly via HttpPost and manually parsed the different values with a custom XML parser. I know this might not be the best of the choices but SOAP is just old school now.